# Ruby - How to keep \n when I print out strings

Tags: ruby

I would like to keep `\n` when I print out strings in ruby,

Like now, if I use `puts` or `print`, `\n` will end up with a newline:

```
pry(main)> print "abc\nabc"
abc
abc
```

is there a way to let ruby print it out like: `abc\nabc` ?

**UPDATE**

Sorry that maybe I didn't make it more clear. I am debugging my regexps, so when I output a string, if a `\n` is displayed as a `\n`, not a newline, it would be easier for me to check. So @slivu 's answer is exactly what I want. Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you want a newline in your string or do you want a literal `'\n'`?

Comment: @muistooshort I think he wants a _literal_ `\n`

Comment: @lkjoel: Or maybe he wants a newline and `str.inspect`, only larryzhao knows for sure.

Comment: @muistooshort, str.inspect? What do you mean?

Comment: @lkjoel: `puts "where is\npancakes house?".inspect`

Comment: Hi @muistooshort @lkjoel Thanks guys for giving me the answer. I am debugging my Regexp. So it would be more clear when I output the string, the `\n` is literally displayed in the string, not results in a newline. That's all I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i would suggest to use `p` instead of `puts`/`print`:

```
p "abc\nabc"
=> "abc\nabc"
```

and in fact with `pry` you do not need to use any of them, just type your string and enter:

```
str = "abc\nabc"
=> "abc\nabc"
str
=> "abc\nabc"
```

Comment: This is nice, but I do not see a equivalent 'p' method for writing to files under IO.  Instead I've found that using str.inspect gives you an escaped string that puts will happily print.

Answer (score 2):

Because \n is a special keyword, you have to *escape* it, by adding a backslash before the special keyword (and because of that, backslashes must also be escaped), like so: `abs\\nabc`. If you wanted to print `\\n`, you would have to replace it to be `abs\\\\n`, and so on (two backslashes to display a backslash).

You can also just use single quotes instead of double quotes so that special keywords will not be interpreted. This, IMHO, is bad practice, but if it makes your code look nicer, I guess it's worth it :)

Here are some examples of ways you can escape (sort of like a TL;DR version):

```
puts 'abc\nabc' # Single quotes ignore special keywords
puts "abc\\nabc" # Escaping a special keyword (preferred technique, IMHO)
p "abc\nabc" # The "p" command does not interpret special keywords
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, strings in a single quote literal, like 'abc\nabc' will not be interpolated.

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > print 'abc\nabc'
abc\nabc => nil
```

vs with double quotes

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > print "abc\nabc"
abc
abc => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this

```
puts 'abc\nabc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %q to create a string for example:

```
  str = %q{abc\nklm}
  puts str #=> 'abc\nklm'
```

or

```
  puts %q{abc\nklm}
```

or use escape character

```
  puts "abc\\nklm"
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the string: `abc\nabc`
The coded string must be: `abc\\nabc` which will not generate a newline.